# exception_notification gem raises ActionView::Template::Error (code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-16)) only on Heroku production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, exception-notification

I create rails app deployed on Heroku.
also, `exception_notification` gem enabled.

when it is on development setup ActionMailer to Gmail,
everything is fine and sends a notification from Gmail address.

but when it comes to production environment on Heroku,
I get following error when server trying to send a email.

`ActionView::Template::Error (code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-16))`

Could anyone tell me what's happening here?

Comment: Same error here. Heroku guys, if you are reading this, please take into account that it is urgent. We have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: Addition: we have resolved the problem by removing Windows line endings from our views.

Comment: Might be a problem with assets not being pre-compiled properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue was raised on the main repository (see [here](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/issues/103)), but so far was not addressed.

You might want to take a look at this fork to the exception_notification gem, specifically this commit which tries to deal with the problem:
https://github.com/alanjds/exception_notification/commit/048fc6be972189e62ca3b9453d19233ec5773016

To use this fork I pointed the gem to it, like so:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'exception_notification', git: 'git://github.com/alanjds/exception_notification.git'
```

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: This appears to be a problem in 3.0.0, wiring it down to the latest 2.x version, `gem 'exception_notification', '2.6.1'` works as well.

Comment: Have a look at Marco's newer answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900132/168034

Answer (score 1):

Quick adjustment to solution by hananamar, otherwise you'll get an error:

```
gem 'exception_notification', :git => 'git://github.com/alanjds/exception_notification.git', :require => 'exception_notifier'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but since I got the same issue some days ago, I wanted to share here that I solved it by forcing the latest version of the gem on my Heroku app.

```
gem 'exception_notification', '3.0.1'
```

I guess the problem was with version 3.0.0 and it is fixed on 3.0.1.